# Is it valid html5 to have a heading <h2> in a <figure> element?

Tags: html

Just wondering if the following code would be considered valid html5:

```
<figure>
    <h2><a href="#">link</a></h2>
    <a href="#"><img src="" /></a>
</figure>
```

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options

Comment: @Juhana, thank you, it seems it is valid HTML5. Now I still wonder if it's something that would be considered sensible HTML5. (nevermind, I see someone answered that too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Read about this figcaption and figure element of HTML5
[Read this for more.](http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/)